# What is the default Isolation level in case of Doctrine using ZF1 and ZF2 and MySql as database?

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, isolation-level

We are using `Doctrine` as ORM, Framework `ZF1` and `ZF2`, and Database `MySql`. I know the default isolation level for `innodb` engine is `Repeatable Read`. Since I am using the `Doctrine` as ORM what is the default `isolation level`? In this [document](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/transactions.html#transactions) it is stated as below:

> The default transaction isolation level of a Doctrine\DBAL\Connection is chosen by the underlying platform but it is always at least READ_COMMITTED.

What made me more confused was from the another article from the Doctrine itself. I this [document](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/changelog/migration_2_5.html) it is stated as follow:

> This could result in unpredictable results because an explicit WITH (NOLOCK) table hint tells SQL Server to run a specific query in transaction isolation level READ UNCOMMITTED instead of the **default READ COMMITTED** transaction isolation level. Therefore there now is a distinction between LockMode::NONE and null to be able to tell Doctrine whether to add table lock hints to queries by intention or not.

**Can anyone explain what is the default isolation level for Doctrine?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For `MySql` the default isolation level is `Repeatable Read.`
>
> For `MSSql` the default isolation level is `Read Committed`.

Unless you change the default setting of the middleware(ORM) the following statement is valid:

> The default transaction isolation level of a Doctrine\DBAL\Connection
>   is chosen by the underlying platform.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure what the default isolation level is you can set it once and for all with [SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-transaction.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Connection`'s [getTransactionIsolation()](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.5/class-Doctrine.DBAL.Connection.html) method to determine the active transaction's isolation level.